# how to scroll div to top or left to see dynamically created elements?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am creating div dynamically inside a div with negative margins, but my div outer scroller is not activating to scroll and see those dynamically created div.

HTML code

```
<html>
<body align="center">

  <div id "TC" class = "Tile_container">
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Here i am creating tile container with x scroll and y scroll.

CSS code

```
.Tile_container
{
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  background-color: lightgray;
  position: relative;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

JS code

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  var tileContainer = document.getElementsByClassName("Tile_container")[0];

  var newTile = document.createElement("div");

  newTile.setAttribute("class", "PlayerTile");

  var strTop = "" + (-100) + "px";

  var strLeft  = ""+ (-100) + "px";

  newTile.style.left = strLeft;
  newTile.style.top = strTop;

  tileContainer.appendChild(newTile);

});
```

My scrollers are activating when i create inner div at position more than the Tile_container div dimension.

can anyone please tell how to scroll and see those created div. in that div i have other functionalities to add.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have moved the *PlayerTile* off the top and left of the parent div.

`overflow-x` and `overflow-y` will not scroll for contents that are off the top or left.

Scrolling to the right and down works fine.

```js
var tileContainer = document.getElementById("TC");

window.onload = (function() {
  var newTile = document.createElement("div");
  newTile.id = 'newtile';
  newTile.setAttribute("class", "PlayerTile");
  tileContainer.appendChild(newTile);
});

function moveTile(direction, value) {
  const tile = document.getElementById('newtile');
  if (direction === 'horizontal') {
    tile.style.left = 
      Number(tile.style.left.replace('px', '')) +
        value + 'px';
  } else {
    tile.style.top =
      Number(tile.style.top.replace('px', '')) +
        value + 'px';
  }
}

const moveRight = () => moveTile('horizontal', 60);
const moveLeft = () => moveTile('horizontal', -60);
const moveUp = () => moveTile('vertical', -12);
const moveDown = () => moveTile('vertical', 12);

function reset() {
  const tile = document.getElementById('newtile');
  tile.style.left = tile.style.top = '12px';
}
```

```css
.Tile_container {
  height: 140px;
  width: 90%;
  background-color: lightgray;
  position: relative;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.PlayerTile {
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: dodgerBlue;
  position: absolute;
  top: 12px;
  left: 12px;
}
```

```html
Move Tile: <button onclick="moveRight()">Right</button>
<button onclick="moveLeft()">Left</button>
<button onclick="moveUp()">Up</button>
<button onclick="moveDown()">Down</button>
<button onclick="reset()">Reset</button><br/>

<div id="TC" class="Tile_container"></div>
```

Comment: thank you for the reply terrymorse, but i dont want to change the position of any of the dynamically created divs there are other thing that are depended on it. is there any other alternative than to make div scroll and see the inner div

Comment: @V01 I don't know of any way to position a child element above and to the left of its parent, and still have it visible.

Comment: i think that can solve my issue in diff way thank you